# sed find replace regex repacing CSS transition with a mixin

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I have 12k lines of SCSS code and I need to replace all CSS transitions like this:

```
transition: background .3s ease;
```

or

```
-webkit-transition: background .3s ease;
```

with a SASS mixin

```
@include _transition(background .3s ease);
```

After lots of research I've end up with a sed command like this

```
sed -i '' 's/transition: ([a-zA-Z0-9.]*);/@include _transition\((\1)\);/' *
```

But of course it doesn't work. I'm using a Mac and the error I get is:

```
sed: 1: "s/transition: ([a-zA-Z0 ...": \1 not defined in the RE
```

Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `space` inside the character class and you don't need to escape `(` , `)` in the replacement part. Normal sed uses BRE(Basic regular expression) so the capturing group must  be like `\(blah blah\)` not like `(blahblah)`

```
sed 's/transition: \([a-zA-Z 0-9.]*\);/@include _transition(\1);/g' file
```

**Example:**

```
$ cat file
transition: background .3s ease;
foo
$ sed 's/transition: \([a-zA-Z 0-9.]*\);/@include _transition(\1);/g' file
@include _transition(background .3s ease);
foo
```

Comment: I don't think it works for the second example.  I get this:  `-webkit-@include _transition(background .3s ease);`

Comment: @AvinashRaj You're awesome and your answer is awesome. It works.

Comment: @David You're right. I made it work that way that firstly I've run sed which replaced all -webkit prefixed transitions, then second one to replace not prefixed ones.